# error: request for member ... which is of non-class type

Tags: c++

I realize the error is coming from using vectors in a custom class, but I have been struggling how to fix them. How do I call vector methods when its part of the class object?

These are the errors I am getting:

```
Word.cpp: In member function ‘void Word::addPosition(int)’:
Word.cpp:20: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘((Word*)this)->Word::positions’, which is of non-class type ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*’
Word.cpp: In member function ‘int Word::getPosition(int)’:
Word.cpp:26: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘((Word*)this)->Word::positions’, which is of non-class type ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*’
Word.cpp:27: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘((Word*)this)->Word::positions’, which is of non-class type ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*’
Word.cpp:29: error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >’ to ‘int’ in return
```

Header

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Word {
  public:
    Word();
    ~Word();
    void setWord(std::string);
    void addPosition(int);
    std::string getWord();
    int getPosition(int);
  private:
    std::string word;
    std::vector<int> *positions;
};
```

Implementation

```
#include "Word.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

Word::Word() {
    this->word = "";
    this->positions = new std::vector<int>(5);
}

void Word::setWord(std::string s) {
    this->word = s;
}

void Word::addPosition(int i) {
    this->positions.push_back(i);
}

std::string Word::getWord() {
    return this->word;
}

int Word::getPosition(int i) {
    if (i < this->positions.size() && i > 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->positions.size(); i++) {
            if (i == j) {
                return positions[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

edit: Is this a better way to set up the class?
header:

```
    #pragma once
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    class Word {
      public:
        Word();
        ~Word();
        void setWord(std::string);
        void addPosition(int);
        std::string getWord();
        int getPosition(int);
      private:
        std::string word;
        std::vector<int> positions;
    };
```

implementation:

```
Word::Word(){
    word = "";
}

void Word::setWord(std::string s){
    this -> word = s;
}
void Word::addPosition(int i){
    this -> positions.push_back(i);
}
std::string Word::getWord(){
    return this -> word;
}
int Word::getPosition(int i){
    if (i < this -> positions.size() && i > 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j<this -> positions.size(); i++) {
            if (i == j) {
                return (this->positions)[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

but now I am getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Unless you have a good reason (i.e. the instructor will fail your assignment grade), there is no reason for `positions` to be a dynamic allocation in this code. It should just be a regular `std::vector<int>`. And I'm leery about the initial size of 5, as I don't think that will do what you think it will if you're relying on `addPositon()` to start adding data in slot-0 of the vector.

Comment: Your use of pointers is confusing you. But using pointers in this situation is wrong. Just don't use pointers! `std::vector<int> positions;` not `std::vector<int> *positions;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`positions` is a pointer. You need to dereference it in order to get to the base vector:

`this->positions->size();`

In general, the error you're getting is caused by failing to dereference (because `T*` is not a class type; it's a pointer, and pointers are a primitive type).

Comment: Thanks For the quick response! I feel silly for not recognizing that

Answer (score 10):

In addition to @Chris answer, the de facto problem here is that **you are using a pointer to a vector instead of a vector directly**.
There is no reason to allocate dynamically a vector, because it internally uses dynamic memory to store its elements. The advantage of vector is that it manages its own memory, and that memory its released at the end of its scope: Thats [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Personally I recommend the Going Native 2013 Stroupstrup talk ["The Essence of C++"](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Opening-Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup). He provides pretty examples and explanations about data management in C++: Data vs Handlers of data.

## For those coming from Java: A perspective about memory management in Java and C++

In Java we differentiate two kinds of data: Basic types (Ints, chars, booleans, etc), and objects (Instances of classes). 
Java manages its memory through a Garbage Collector: The Java runtime (The JVM) allocates the memory used by objects on the heap, and what provides you is **a pointer to that allocated object**. So in Java your variables are really **pointers allocated on the stack pointing to the heap memory where the object is allocated** (This is directly related with [the usual problems which noobs have with Java pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)). This allows Java to share ownership of object instances easily: It only tracks (via reference counting) how many variables refers to an specific object.
Occasionally the garbage collector look at the program heap and releases the memory used by objects which reference count have dropped to zero (That is, objects which you are not using yet). So, as you can see, **The GC provides a non-deterministic way to release/manage the memory**.

C++ memory management is dessigned to work **in a deterministic way**. All variables are declared in a specific scope, **which determines its lifetime** When the scope of a variable ends, **the lifetime of that variable ends, and in the case of objects, its destructor its called to execute the apropiated releasing operations**.
Thats known as Resource Acquisition Is Initialization, or RAII.

RAII means that objects manage resources (Memory, file handles, network ports, etc), and the adquisition, use, and release of that resource is **directly linked to the lifetime of the object which manages the resource**. This provides a deterministic and leak-free system to manage resources: Note that "resources" don't refers to memory only, which is the only resource which a Garbage Collector manages. RAII is, in the 99% of the cases, **much more powerfull and secure than a garbage collector**.

`std::vector` is the tipical example of a class that manages a resource (A dynamically allocated resizable array in its case) through RAII.
As you can see, I havent talk about pointers at all: **Pointers have to be used to share ownership of an object, or to allocate a dynamic chunk (Array) of memory**. But note that the first case could be (And must be) achieved through [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one), and the second through RAII-based containers such as `std::vector`.

The problem with your use of a pointer to dynamically-allocate a `std::vector` are:

- `std::vector` manages internally a dynamic array where it allocates the elements, so `std::vector` size (That is, what vector fits in the stack) its only the size of the pointer pointing to the array, and two counters (Integers). Don't worry about the size of vector in the stack (Due to possible stackoverflows): The array is allocated on the heap.
- Using a pointer to allocate dynamically a vector breaks RAII, because the lifetime of the vector instance is not linked to any scope, its lifetime **must be determined by you**, when  you decide to deallocate (`delete`) the vector. Of course manual dynamic memory management its error prone.

Again, I recommend you to view Stroupstrup's talk: He explains this much better than me :)

Comment: I'm coming from java so I never really had to deal with pointers. Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post that. It fills in a huge gap I had in understanding c++.

Comment: @badger0053 glad I could help. Consider to get a C++ book. The C++ FAQ has a thread with a good list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Is this a better way to set up my class by not making it a pointer? I added to the original question

Comment: @badger0053 that question was answered in my edit yet: I have showed you the benefits of RAII and the disadvantages of manual-memory-management. So yes, its better. Raw-pointers and breaking-RAII code is the worst solution possible.

Comment: Just some nits: 1. The pointers (called references) should really be listed with the other basic types. 2. Java uses a tracing GC instead of reference-counting, so cycles can be collected, though you can never depend on any pointer not bein nulled out already (and the object it pointed to potentially being reclaimed) in the finalizer.

Answer (score 2):

`positions` is a pointer, so you need to use indirection:

```
this->positions->push_back(i);
```

**Don't use pointers in this situation**. You're better off using a stack-allocated vector and  initializing it through the constructor:

```
class Word
{
    ...
private:
    std::string word;
    std::vector<int> positions;
};

Word::Word()
    : word(""), positions(5) { }

void Word::addPosition(int i)
{
    this->positions.push_back(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`positions` is a pointer to a vector, the usage should be with the `->` operator:

also, notice that i changed `return positions[j];`

```
#include "Word.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
Word::Word(){
    this -> word = "";
    this -> positions = new std::vector<int>(5);
}

void Word::setWord(std::string s){
    this -> word = s;
}
void Word::addPosition(int i){
    this -> positions->push_back(i);
}
std::string Word::getWord(){
    return this -> word;
}
int Word::getPosition(int i){
    if (i < this -> positions.size() && i > 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j<this -> positions->size(); i++) {
            if (i == j) {
                return (*positions)[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Another solution, will be not to hold a pointer, define the vector like this:

```
private:
    std::string word;
    std::vector<int> positions;
```

And then you should also remove this line `this -> positions = new std::vector<int>(5);`
You should also know that vector enlarges itself when it needs, you do not need to specify that it's initial size if it is small (you should consider doing it for realy large values)

Comment: so if i go with the second option and don't hold a pointer, how do I instantiate positions? I'm confused to how to set up my constructor. If I get rid of it completely I get a symbols not found for architecture error.

Comment: @badger0053 You can initialize positions like any other constructor, in the 'Member Initialization List', but you don't have to! That is why the default constructor is for! no idea about the error, i need to see the exact error...

Comment: If you don't initialize it, how are you supposed to use in the other methods such as getPosition(). The actual error is: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 1):

`positions` is a pointer, so you need `positions->push_back`.

On the other hand, why are you allocating the vector on the heap? It can be a member of the class instead.